# Modify keys and values in a nested dictionary with lists inside of it

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, nested-loops

How can I iterate in a dict that contains a children, which contains a list which contains more dictionaries inside, and add a value if some condition is done

A portion of the dictionary I have is this:

```
{
        "a": "segments",
        "children":
            [{"a": 1,
                "order": "1",
                "price": 1500.0,
                "children":
                    [{
                        "a": "1.1",
                        "order": "2",
                        "price": 75.0,
                        "children": 
                            [{
                                "a": "1.1.1",
                                "order": "3",
                                "price":100.0
                            }]
                    }]

                            // . . . 
                },
                {"a": n,
                "order": "1",
                "price": 100.0,
                "children": 
                        [{
                        "a": "n.1",
                        "order": "2",
                        "price": 1000.0
                        }]
                }]
 }
```

I have been trying to solve it using different for loops in a function, 
but I have not obtained the desired result.

What I want to do is for each children with order 1, go until the last child of him and sum all the prices, then do the same for the order 2, and so on until the last child

I already now that how it is a dictionary and inside of the key children there is a list with more dictionaries I can do several for loops like the followings

```
list_segments = []
first_children = data['children']
for dicts in first_children:

    for segment in dicts['children']:
        list_segments.append(segment)
```

But the problem is that I don't know how to make a function that feeds back with the next child, going through all the children until the end.

The desired output should be a key in all the levels like this:

```
level_price: price order 1 +price order 2 + price price order 3
    level_price: price order 2 + price price order 3
        level_price: price order 3
```

Comment: Write a recursive function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is a recursive function using `async` with the purpose to wait until the last nested level adding the `price`:

```
async def mainfunction(current_level):

    if 'subtree_price' in current_level:
        for child in current_level['children']:
            if 'children' in child:            
                    child = await  mainfunction(child)
    else:     
        current_level = await parentFunction(current_level)       
        if 'children' in current_level:            
            for child in current_level['children']:            
                child = await  mainfunction(child)       
    return current_level

async def parentFunction(current_level):    
    counter = 0    
    if 'price' in current_level:
        if 'children' in current_level:       
            for child in current_level['children']:
                counter += await childfunction(0, child)        
        else:
            current_level['subtree_price'] = current_level['price']           
        current_level['subtree_price'] = counter +  current_level['price']               
    return current_level

async def childfunction(counter, current_level):   
    counter = 0 
    if 'children' in current_level:  
        for child in current_level['children']:
            counter += child['price']
            if 'children' in child:   
                counter += await childfunction(counter, child)        
    return counter + current_level['price']
```

The first you have to do is think about to sum all the `prices` from your current level to the last level. It can be done with the `childfunction`

The `mainfunction` check if your current level (`order`) has already added the total sum done by the `childfunction` (checking if the `subtree_price` exists). If not exists, the `parentfunction` is called which check if exists childs. If they exist it will execute the `childfunction` and the result will be added to the `parent` in your current level. If not, the `subtree_price` will be your own `price`.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I just used the functions and I got the result I wanted, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Traversing a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) requires some method of handling the [recursively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) defined structure, either using an explicit [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) or using a function that calls itself to process its child nodes.

Using a recursive function works as follows: for any node in the tree, total its price and the prices of its children. To obtain child prices, we traverse recursively, calling `tree_total` on each child and passing the accumulated results back up the tree. By the time the recursion terminates, we return to the caller, having visited all the nodes.

```
def tree_total(node):
    price = node["price"] if "price" in node else 0

    if "children" in node:
        price += sum(tree_total(child) for child in node["children"])

    return price

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(tree_total(data)) # => 2775.0
```

Or using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to apply the `tree_total` function to each child of `root`:

```
def tree_total(node):    
    price = node["price"] if "price" in node else 0

    if "children" in node:
        price += sum(map(tree_total, node["children"]))

    return price
```

Here's an iterative solution using a stack, which mimics the call stack in recursion. We begin with the root node as the only item in the stack, then pop the stack, visiting a node and pushing its children and repeating the process until no nodes are left in the stack.

```
def tree_total(node):
    total = 0
    stack = [node]

    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()

        if "price" in node:
            total += node["price"]

        if "children" in node:
            stack.extend(node["children"])

    return total
```

Comment: "Traversing a tree requires recursion." Nothing ever *requires* recursion

Comment: How do you do it then? An explicit stack is just another way of computing the recursively defined relationship between the nodes.

Comment: The wording colloquially implies you are required to use a recursive function, which as you understand, is not necessary (use your own stack)

Comment: OK, I see the confusion--I'll improve my  word choice. Thanks.